# What does "to be counted outside the 'three plus one' cap" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

> Japan has made these moves far easier for players from the ASEAN region by a ‘visa exemption’ that allows nationals from most of the zone **to be counted outside the ‘three plus one’ cap** that otherwise applies, and that’s seen several others enjoy brief, if unsuccessful, stints across the top three flights of the country. ([Source](http://www.foxsportsasia.com/football/asian-football/762290/teerasil-has-much-to-prove-in-japan/))

I don't really get the meaning of the sentence above, especially the part "to be counted outside the ‘three plus one’ cap that otherwise applies, and that’s seen several others enjoy brief, if unsuccessful, stints across the top three flights of the country"

I'd really appreciate it if you help me understand it. And it would be helpful if you paraphrase it in the simplest way.

Comment: Source please.  I suspect this is some rule about foreign players in Japanese baseball (or some other sport), but there is not enough context to prove this. Please link to the full original, if possible.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.foxsportsasia.com/football/asian-football/762290/teerasil-has-much-to-prove-in-japan/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link explains what the [three-plus-one](http://www.goal.com/en/news/1775/asian-editorials/2009/01/29/1082990/asian-debate-is-the-3-plus-1-rule-changing-asian-football) rule is: basically a Japanese football team can have a maximum of three players from outside the ASEAN region and a further player from within the ASEAN region.

A rule that places a limit on something can be called a [cap](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cap).

If somebody is **counted outside** the three-plus-one cap, it means that they are not counted within the three-plus-one, and so the cap does not apply to them.

A [stint](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stint) is a period of time doing a particular job. **The top three flights of the country** may be a (somewhat unconventional) reference to tiers J1 to J3 in the [Japanese Association Football League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_association_football_league_system).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But one more thing, I'm not sure what " **stints across the top three flights of the country** " means in this case. Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: I have updated my answer.